# How can I use autocomplete in a jQuery in an each loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm generating a table usinf jQuery. in each row I have an input field, that should search some values from DB usibg autocomplete. first row works perfectley but with the second I have problems, it returns in autocomplete only a value from the field above, I have no idea how can i fix it... can somebody help?

here is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/JsonWeekEvents",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (i, val) {

            var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.Id);
            //trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + "&nbsp;" + '</td>');
            trow.append('<td style="padding:5px; width:100px; height:70px"></td>');
            trow.append('<td valign="top" style="padding:2px; width:150px; height:100px">' +
                            '<div class="ui-widget">' +
                                    '<input  size="10" maxlength="10" id="tagsM" class="tags" />' +
                                        '<input type="button" id="addBtn" onclick="addEvent();" size="5" value="+" /><br/>' +
                                             '<div style="text-align:center" id="desc_Num">' + val.Monday + '</div >' +
                            '</div >' +
                        '</td>');

            tab.append(trow);
        });

        $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
        $("#weekEvents").html(tab);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
});
var tab = $('<table class=MyTable border=1 ></table>');
var thead = $('<thead></thead>');

thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
thead.append('<th style="padding:5px">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');

tab.append(thead);


tab.on("focus", "input[class='tags']", function (e) {

    //var prefix = $('.tags').val();

    $('.tags').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetSearchValue",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { search: $('.tags').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {

                            label: item.Title + ', ' + item.Description, value: item.Title,

                            Id: item.Id,
                            Title: item.Title,
                            Description: item.Description,
                            Location: item.Location
                        }
                    }));
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Error!" + xhr);
                },

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I would also advise taking the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I suspect your issue stems from `data: { search: $('.tags').val() }`. If there are more than 1 element with `tags` class, this can cause unexpected results.

Comment: I think it too, but how can I avoid it and generate unique class ir id name? Do You have any idea?

Comment: You can use `request.term` instead. Please see: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: will try this out, thanks fir an advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would advise something like the following:

```
tab.on("focus", "input[class='tags']", function(e) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-autocomplete")) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetSearchValue", {
            search: request.term
          },
          function(data) {
            response($.map(data, function(item) {
              return {
                label: item.Title + ', ' + item.Description,
                value: item.Title,
                Id: item.Id,
                Title: item.Title,
                Description: item.Description,
                Location: item.Location
              }
            }));
          });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This will initialize autocomplete on `focus` event. If it's already initialized, that will not be repeated. The source will perform a GET request and search for the `request.term` from the User's input on that specific field.

Comment: @Dimitri I am glad that helped. I hope you want to upvote the answer and mark it.

Comment: I'm new here. I've marked it but have no idea how can I upvote it...

Comment: @Dimitri on the left of the Answer, there are Up and Down arrows to Upvote or Downvote a post or an answer. It's all in the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: oh, ok, by me it not really visible :) (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)